# How can I scale Gatsby Images by a fixed factor?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, gatsby

I'm building a gatsby blog for an artist, which means I have to display paintings. My client requests that the painting are  displayed while sharing a scaling factor. What I mean by that is that a painting that is twice the width of another one in real life, should be twice as large on the website. I have tried and heard of multiple ways but none really fits me. The most convenient methods I've tried being being :

1. Using the *zoom* css property, but it isn't supported by firefox
2. using the *transform: scale* property

So I was wondering if there's a way to scale all my queried images by a single factor, relative to the original file dimensions.

```
query galeryQuery($slug: String!) {
  allWpMediaItem(filter: {wpParent: {node: {slug: {eq: $slug}}}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        title
        description
        localFile {
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData(/* Probably something needed here */)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My current query looks like this, I've tried using **outputPixelDensities**, **breakpoints** and some other parameters but none seems to work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you describe what went wrong when you used the transform scale - which seems like the obvious way to do it (once you've decided on the relative layout of your gallery for any particular viewport dimensions of course).

Comment: When using transform, the actual element still takes its original space, meaning I will either have overflow, or the same problem, being all images eventually reaching the same width

Comment: I was assuming everything would be set at its naatural dimensions and then the container scaled, not each bit individually.